# Overlapping widgets in QLayout

Tags: python, user-interface, qt5, qt3d, pyside2

I want to create a window where is `Qt3DWindow` in the back and some `QPushButton`s above it. However only `Qt3DWindow` animation is shown and `QPushButton`s are not seen. I would also like to have `Qt3DWindow` functional and `QPushButton`s as well (So I can click on the buttons or 3D animation behind). Buttons are only seen when I set `Qt3DWindow` transparency to lower value. Of course in that case buttons are only seen but not functional.

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, *args)

        self.window = Window()  # Qt3DExtras.Qt3DWindow
        self.container = self.createWindowContainer(self.window)

        self.buttons = Buttons()
        self.layout().addWidget(self.buttons.view)  # QtWidgets.QGraphicsView
        self.layout().addWidget(self.container)
```

Comment: [`QMainWindow`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html) has its own proprietary layout type -- you can't simply use it as you would any other layout.  You need to place your `Buttons` and `container` under a parent `QWidget` and pass *that* to [`QMainWindow.setCentralWidget`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#setCentralWidget).

Comment: @G.M.  Thanks! It is easier to manipulate `QLayout` in `QWidget`. However I am still unable to put `container` behind.

Comment: What do you mean by `behind'?  Do you mean z-order?  Please edit your question and add the new code you've tried.

Comment: Yes, I mean z-order. I just moved code from `QMainWindow` to `QWidget` and added custom `QLayout`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QWidget::createWindowContainer() will handle the geometry of the window however it does change the fact that the managed window still overlays the window that contains the widget. So any child of that widget will not be visible as it will be obscured by the Qt3DWindow.

Only viable alternative is move the widgets you want to overlay into their own window and handles it's geometry yourself.

Or use a Scene3D inside a QDeclarativeWidget but that will affect performance.

Answer (score 1):

As per the comment, `QMainWindow` uses its own layout type which is responsible for a large part (most) of its functionality -- dock widgets, toolbars etc.

Rather than just add widgets to *that* layout you need to create your own widget hierarchy and pass that to [`QMainWindow::setCentralWidget`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#setCentralWidget).

If you want the `Buttons` to lie in front of the `container` you can probably use a `QGridLayout`.

So, you could try something like (untested)...

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, *args)

        self.window = Window()  # Qt3DExtras.Qt3DWindow
        self.container = self.createWindowContainer(self.window)
        self.buttons = Buttons()
        central_widget = QWidget()
        central_widget_layout = QGridLayout()
        central_widget_layout.addWidget(self.container, 0, 0, 2, 1)
        central_widget_layout.addWidget(self.buttons.view, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        central_widget.setLayout(central_widget_layout)
        setCentralWidget(central_widget)
```

Comment: Thanks! But this sadly does not work. `Qt3DWindow` still lies in the front.

Comment: Really?  Are you sure you're adding the widgets to the layout in the correct order -- `self.container` and *then* `self.buttons.view`?  You could also try calling [`self.buttons.view.raise()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#raise) to force the z-order.

Comment: Yes. I have changed the order several times and also have used `self.buttons.view.raise_()` and `self.container.lower()` as well.